# How do you subset a data variable using Xarray in python?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am working with a netcdf hail dataset. I am trying to subset the data by elevation ('topo') but I cannot seem to do so. I can slice along latitude and longitude as well as time, most likely due to them being coordinate variables and not data variables. Does anyone know the syntax to do this?

I should mention that my coordinate variables are level, x, y, tp, and case. I think I may have to do something with the case variable to make this work but I am unsure how.

What I tried to do was the methods as follows:

```
elev1 = haildata.sel(topo=1500)
```

which gives me the error:

```
'topo' is not a valid dimension or coordinate
```

and

```
elev1 = haildata[haildata['topo']>=1500.]
```

which gives me the error:

```
Unsupported key-type <class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to make the problem reproducible. We do not know what top is or how it's represented in your dataset, so all we can do is guess what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, we can only guess, since we don't know the format of your dataset.
My guess would be:

```
elev1 = haildata.where(haildata.topo >= 1500)
```

Maybe you also want to add `, drop=True` in the parentheses to get rid of points where topo is less than 1500.